# using method from other activity in Java ( android )

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a conundrum, I do know how to call method from other activity.. crating object etc..

But I have dbHelper.java that deal with creating sql little tables etc and start like:

```
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
.
.
.
}
```

it works fine but i have method there that check when the DB version change and recreate DB tables etc..

like:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // pri zmene verzie DB dropne tabulku
        Log.w("DATA", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion); 
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS plan");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");

        this.onCreate(db);
}
```

but I need to store also shared preference that I use to tell application that its new start... however its kind of strange i try :

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("FS", "1");
    editor.commit();
```

But MODE_PRIVATE get underlined as error, even when I try call method from other activity creating object like this for example:  dataManager db = new dataManager(this); where is method to store shared preference I get still underlined it as error...

Any idea what might be the issue ? I'm learning java but still no idea :-/

Vlad

Comment: What does the error actually say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MODE_PRIVATE` is a constant which is declared in `Context` class. Just change `MODE_PRIVATE` to `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

This works fine inside the Activity's method, cause' `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`

Comment: well it fixed the MODE_PRIVATE but now is underlined getSharedPreferences and it wants to Create method getSharedPreferences (String, Int )

Comment: I don't get it, what is so special about this activity that I can't reference another methods from other activitys, I have 5 others in project and it works fine in all of them.. only difference this one have extend SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: `getSharedPreferences` is also a method of `Context` class. You need to pass a `Context` instance (or it's descendant, in example your `Activity`) to your code and call `getSharedPreferences` on that instance.

Comment: SQLiteOpenHelper is not an Activity! This is a root of all your problems now. You need to pass Context to your class' (`dbHelper`) constructor.

Comment: ah I think I know what you mean. I have this:

 public dbHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

 }

but there might be something missing there, im just not sure what

Comment: Yeah, it is. Save this `context` variable into private field and use in your methods.

Comment: hmm can't get it to work, I will continue tomorrow, I can hardly see :D

Comment: I made it ! just need to sleep and next day I made it to work. you were right. I created  `public dbHelper(Context context) { 
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
  dbHelper.myContext = context;
 }` and use myContext now, thanks for help